# Картинки переносятся на новую строку

Tags: style, html, css, php

На HTML-страничке указал стиль:

```
.img1 {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:35px;
  background:url(image.png);
}
.img1:hover {
  background:url(image2.png);
}
```

За ним следует описание стиля img2, img3, 4, 5, 6... В конце, как положено, закрыл стиль.

Затем следует вставка самих картинок:

```
<a class="img1" href="страница1"></a><a class="img2" href="страница2"></a><a class="img3" href="страница3"></a><a class="img4" href="страница4"></a><a class="img5" href="страница5"></a>
```

Но каждая картинка вставляется на новой строке.

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки шли одна за другой, без пропусков, без переносов, одной сплошной линией?..

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

```
display: inline-block;
```

или

```
float: left;
```

А вообще для чего столько классов? Если у вас стили разные используйте id. А общие свойства вынесите в общий класс. Например:

```
.imgCls { display:inline-block; width:200px; height:35px; }
#img1 {background:url(image.png); } 
#img1:hover { background:url(image2.png); }
```

и т.д.

Comment: Всё супер. Работает, как и надо было. Большое спасибо.

Размеры картинок разные. Значит, общее свойство у них будет только 
display:inline-block
Пусть остается как было... Мне так привычнее.

Большое спасибо за ответ. Очень помог.

Comment: Вопрос не забывайте закрывать. И буду благодарен за плюсик.

Comment: Жаль, недостаточно очков уважения. Я тут новенький.
Я отметил ответ, как правильный.
Большое спасибо

Comment: Кстати inline-block для <a> работает нормально, но если вдруг будешь делать тоже самое например для <li>, то для кроссбраузерности для старых браузеров (firefox2; ie6,7) нужно будет хаки добавлять.